# DBFlow(Model Cannot be cast To Model)

Tags: android, android-studio, orm

I have two database Model, one is test model the other one is image model.
I'm storing the image as byte in my database.
When i'm retrieving the byte from database, I'm getting this error.

```
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: upload.syncdatabase.TestModel cannot be cast to upload.syncdatabase.ImageModel
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at upload.syncdatabase.MainActivity$MyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:230)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:582)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:649)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-17 02:17:21.143 22974-22974/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

In my Adapter, Im calling testmodel and the imagemodel. Because the image stored in imagetable and the other info is in test model.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        private List<TestModel> mDatas;
        private List<ImageModel> xDatas;

        public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable List<TestModel> datas,@Nullable List<ImageModel> pDatas) {
            super();
            mContext = context;
            mDatas = datas;
            xDatas=pDatas;
        }

        public void swapItems(@NonNull final List<TestModel> datas) {
            mDatas = datas;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (mDatas == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return mDatas.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mDatas.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtName;
            TextView txtNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                holder.txtNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            TestModel data = (TestModel) getItem(position);
            holder.txtName.setText(data.POI);
            holder.txtNumber.setText(String.valueOf(data.POIAddress));

            ImageModel dataM = (ImageModel) getItem(0);//getting errors here

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: add   
        `public getItem2(int position) {
            return xDatas.get(position);
        } ` and get `ImageModel dataM = (ImageModel) getItem2(0);`

Comment: where will i add this?

Comment: in your `Adapter class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in your `Adapter`

```
public ImageModel getItem2(int position) { return xDatas.get(position); }
```

and get `ImageModel`  data in `getView(....)`

```
ImageModel dataM = (ImageModel) getItem2(0);
```

Comment: I already added the getItem2 but it has an error, Invalid method declaration, return type required?

Comment: add like `public ImageModel getItem2(int position) { return xDatas.get(position); }`

Comment: oh problem solved. it should be public Object getItem2(int position) {

            return pData.get(position);

        }.. thank you!

Comment: @CharlesGalvez Exactly you got it.